# In ZMQ PUSH/PULL How to know socket status(connected or not) in python?

Tags: python-3.x, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm a beginner and I've tried using with ZMQ monitor queue but I'm not getting expected result

Comment: I do not think you can. Why do need to know this? ZeroMQ handles the details of connecting/disconnecting so you don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *How to know socket status(connected or not) in python?*

a ) By exception(s) :
thrown in common in situations, when the requested call to API ( API service ) was asked in such a moment, the socket-object was not in a state to execute it
*( for this, **see the native-API documentation** for details on reporting failed state via `zmq_errno()` et al )*

**b ) By introspection** :
 ZeroMQ API reports the **`rc`** ( Return Code detecting the `{ PASS | FAIL }` result of a native-API call )

---

Python wrappers ( pyzmq vX.Y ), the more the recent efforts to re-wrap this already wrapper-re-formulated native-API tools, complicate the way, how to learn intrinsic details about the `{ PASS | FAIL }` result of the most recent re-wrapped call to native-API.

Best read first the original ZeroMQ native API documentation, so as to see what gets when reported via the native **`zmq_errno()`** and all the rest about the internal state(s) of the system is to be deducted from FSA-events ( reported via the native-API **`socket_monitor`** tool ( having this again re-wrapped by a wrapper-mediated counterparty in `pyzmq` - so test its suitability for your use-case ) ).